# I'm having some Python issues with defining user-input based variables

Tags: python, syntax

I know you've seen this before, but I really need help here.
I've been creating a Python based "math testing" program for my Tech Ed. class, and I've been struggling with properly defining the answers in numeric form, below is my sub-par Python script. If there are any other issues besides my current issue, please let me know. Below is the source code causing the issue.

```
print("e = 16 , a = 6 | a*10-e ")
answer = input()

if answer = 44:
    print("You got it!")
    print(" n = 186 | 4+n/2")
if answer = 97:
    print("You got it!")
    print(" a = 4 , b = 6 | b^(2)-a")
if answer = 32:
    print(" you got it!")
else:
 print("Sorry, thats incorrect")
 print("please restart the test!")
```

Comment: You need a separate `if/else` for each question. And printing the next question shouldn't be in the `if` block.

Comment: Thank You! I'll do that and try again

Comment: (1) Convert the input to a number. (2) Equality test is the `==` operator. (3)You can replace here all but the first "if" by "elif" to make it work then.

Comment: @MichaelButscher actually `elif` won't work here, he needs separate `if/else`s

Comment: _If there are any other issues besides my current issue_ What is the current issue?

Comment: @chuck2002 I didn't understand the desired logic of the program properly.

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a `str`, if you want python to treat it as an integer do:

```
answer = int(input())
```

Also, the way your code works right now all three answers will be accepted for the first question. You need an individual `else` for each question in case its answer is wrong, something like:

```
if answer == 44:  # Note '==' and not '='
    print("You got it!")
else:
     print("Sorry, thats incorrect")
     print("please restart the test!")
print(" n = 186 | 4+n/2")
# The same for the rest of the questions
```

That way there's only one correct answer for every question.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `else:` for each `if`, not just one at the end. And the questions should not be in the `if` -- the way you did it you check the answer to the previous question against the next result. Also if comparisons should use == .

And you have to ask for input for each question, and convert it to integer.

```
print("e = 16 , a = 6 | a*10-e ")
answer = int(input())
if answer == 44:
    print("You got it!")
else:
    print("Sorry, thats incorrect")

print(" n = 186 | 4+n/2")
answer = int(input())
if answer == 97:
    print("You got it!")
else:
    print("Sorry, thats incorrect")

print(" a = 4 , b = 6 | b^(2)-a")
answer = int(input())
if answer == 32:
    print(" you got it!")
else:
    print("Sorry, thats incorrect")
```

To avoid all this duplication, you might want to make a list of questions and answers, and use a loop.

```
questions = (("e = 16 , a = 6 | a*10-e ", 44),
             (" n = 186 | 4+n/2", 97),
             ("a = 4 , b = 6 | b^(2)-a", 32))
for question, answer in questions:
    response = int(input(question))
    if answer == response:
        print("you got it!")
    else:
        print("Sorry, that's incorrect")
```